# AngularJS stops working after ajax-updating it via JSF

Tags: angularjs, jsf, primefaces

I've the below JSF + AngularJS form:

```
<h:form id="fmMain1" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">
    <p:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{testBean.updateMode}"
        update="@form" process="@form"/>

    <h:panelGrid rendered="#{testBean.mode eq 'EDIT'}">
        <input ng-show="true" type="text" ng-model="sometext" />
        <h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid rendered="#{testBean.mode eq 'VIEW'}">
        <input ng-show="true" type="text" ng-model="sometext" />
        <h1>Hello {{ sometext }}</h1>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

With this managed bean:

```
public class TestBean {

    private String mode = "VIEW";

    public void updateMode(){
        if(mode.equals("VIEW"))
            mode="EDIT";
        else
            mode="VIEW";
    }

    // +getter+setter
}
```

This works when page is rendered for first time. But it stops working after clicking "Edit" button which ajax-updates the form via JSF. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that we need to compile the new DOM again after the ajax call to new html as below:

```
$scope.compileHTML = function($el) {
    ($compile($el))($scope);
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

after this call this:

```
$('#dest').load('replace.html', function() {
    $dest.scope().compileHTML($dest);
});
```

The function .scope() allows to find a correct AngularJS scope for a HTML element. It doesn't need to point directly to element with ng-controller, any element under the ng-controller can be used